# How to restrict access by NGINX basic_auth for every URL except one URL?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Here is my snippet of nginx:

```
     location / {
             # First attempt to serve request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             try_files $uri /index.html;
             auth_basic "Private Property";
             auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
     }

     location /schedule {
             auth_basic off;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:25000;
     }
```

However, on /schedule, it is showing below page. How to fix this?[image].

Comment: What do you see in the Nginx access log and Nginx error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 location = /schedule {
         auth_basic off;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:25000;
 }
```